# Bypass "Program is trying to access ... Outlook" Dialog Box

Tags: c#, outlook-2007, add-in

I'm facing one issue while writing Office Outlook 2007 Add-In, I'm accessing the email contents of email currently being sent by capturing Send event. Everything works fine but when accessing the subject/body of the email through Outlook.MailItem object (in C#), it prompts a dialog box to allow/deny this program to access. Can anyone help how to bypass this dialog box and allow the program to access MailItem ?

Thanks

Safiullah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don think it is possible, MSFT has placed this alert box to avoid an illegal mail box access by malicious program... However, following guys claim that they can by-pass:

http://www.ablebits.com/programming-outlook-security/index.php

Comment: means no solution !!! is there any way to let the users to "Allow" once and then prompt should not come any more in future ?